# How do we find the constants of pdf using the $\mathrm{E}(X)$?

Tags: density-function

I have a pdf of cont random variable as $(a+bx^2)$ between $0$ and $1$. how do I find the constants $a$ and $b$ when my $\mathrm{E}(X)=3/5$?

Comment: Please add the [`self-study`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag and read the tag-wiki carefully.

Answer (score 6):

Apply the properties of the pdf $f(x)$ and the definition of the expected value. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function):

> The probability density function is nonnegative everywhere, and its
>   integral over the entire space is equal to 1.

So in your case it is required that:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,\mathrm{dx} = 1
$$

Next, review the definition of the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case). In your case:

$$
\mathrm{E}(X) = \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\,\mathrm{dx} = 3/5
$$

Evaluate the integrals and solve the resulting equations for $a$ and $b$.